# Why to make the last node.next point to Tail instead of NULL in a linked-list?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Please read the question carefully, Considering this implementation, why would anyone use the **list's Tail or End** to mark the last element in a linked list **instead of just using NULL**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    int ID;
    struct Node* Previous;
    struct Node* Next;
};

void AddNodeAtEnd(struct Node** Start, struct Node** End, struct Node* NewNode) {
    if (*Start == *End && *End == NULL) {
        *Start = NewNode;
        *End = NewNode;
        NewNode->Previous = Start; // normal implementation would do this NewNode->Previous = NULL;
        NewNode->Next = End; // // normal implementation would do this NewNode->Next = NULL; 
    }
    else {
        struct Node* OldNode = *End;
        OldNode->Next = NewNode;
        NewNode->Previous = OldNode;
        NewNode->Next = End;
        *End = NewNode;
    }
}

void PrintList_Method1(struct Node** Start, struct Node** End) {
    if (*Start == NULL && *End == NULL) {
        printf("\nThe List Is Empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node* CurrentNode = *Start;
        while (CurrentNode != End)
        {
            printf("ID = %d\n", CurrentNode->ID);
            CurrentNode = CurrentNode->Next;
        }
    }
}
```

in main() the call would look like

```
int main()
{
    struct Node* List1Start = NULL;
    struct Node* List1End = NULL;

    struct Node* N1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    N1->ID = 15;
    struct Node N2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));;
    N2->ID = 30;
    PrintList(&List1Start, &List1End);
    AddNodeAtEnd(&List1Start, &List1End, N1);
    AddNodeAtEnd(&List1Start, &List1End, N2);
    PrintList(&List1Start, &List1End);
}
```

would there be advantages or disadvantages of using this method instead of using NULL

Comment: You are allocating `List1End`, then you set `List1End = NULL`. It should be `struct Node* List1Start = malloc`, don't `NULL` it, and pass `PrintList(&List1Start, &List1End);` etc. You also have to use `malloc` for each node being added. Consider starting with a single-linked list first.

Comment: @cloud em This code     struct Node** List1Start = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    struct Node** List1End = malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    *List1End = NULL;
    *List1Start = NULL; does not make a sense

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, @Vlad from Moscow , the call is just an example, the `NewNode->Next = End;` for marking the last node instead of `NewNode->Next = NULL;` is what I wish to have an answer to

Comment: If you want to print the entire list then you only need the "head". If you want to print a section of that list, then you supply `from` and `to` to the print function. Maybe that relates to your question! You are using a double-linked list (not close to completion) it needs both `prev` and `next` to go forward and backward.

Comment: Please forgive the incomplete implementation, I only took the lines of code that I'm interested in from the original code and pasted it here, and I wonder why to use End instead of NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clarified in the comments that you are asking about `->Next = End`.

What are you doing is using the address of the tail pointer to signify the end of the list. This is a *horrible* idea.

There's absolutely no reason to do so. People know what encountering NULL means. Using confusing constants just hinders readability with no benefit.

It's error prone. `End` now has two unrelated purposes. Confusing code like this is exactly what software developers try to avoid. The most important job of a programmer is to produce readable code.

And it's a lot less safe. While trying to follow a `NULL` by accident will terminate your program in a very consistent and easy to debug manner, following an otherwise-valid pointer doesn't have those benefits.

You're not even consistent, using a combination of `NULL`, `Start` and `End` to indicate a lack of node. Just use `NULL` instead of inventing two new worthless and harmful constants.

---

A cleaner implementation:

```c
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
   Note *head;
   Node *tail;
} List;

void List_append(List *list, Node *node) {
   Node **tail_ptrptr = list->tail == NULL ? &( list->tail ) : &( tail->next );
   node->prev = *tail_ptrptr;
   node->next = NULL;
   *tail_ptrptr = node;
   list->tail = node;
}

void List_print(List *list) {
   for (Node node = list->head; node; node = node->next) {
      printf("%d\n", node->value);
   }
}

int main(void) {
   List list = { 0 };

   List_append(&list, create_node(15));
   List_append(&list, create_node(30));

   List_print(&list);

   // ...

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: not asking for an implementation, but asking why the implementation in the question the way it is?

Comment: I've tested it and its working correctly, but again not my question, its just a something to call the function for now

Comment: I asked because it's weird, the call and the if-else is just for the sake of question

Comment: the most straight forward way just to form a question about this line of code `NewNode->Next = End;`

Comment: @cloudem This implementation has both "head" and "tail" like in the question. Except they are contained in a structure. You can do it without keeping track of "tail". But for example, each time you append a node at the end, and you don't know where the end is at, you would have to iterate starting from "head" and find the "tail". If somebody else is doing it differently you have to ask that person.

Comment: I'll use this answer to clarify my question

Comment: I have updated my answer.